# Printing an array multiple times

Tags: python, arrays

```
present_coefiecients = random.sample(xrange(1,50),5)
present_value = random.sample(xrange(1,100),5)
present_weights = ap.array('0;0;0;0;0')
print present_coefiecients
print present_value
print present_weights
c = [a*b for a,b in zip(present_coefiecients,present_value)]
layer_1 = ap.log2(c)
print layer_1
```

how can I run these set of instructions 50 times so i could get different values of layer_1 each time

Comment: Put this code in a function and invoke the function in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for this just use a `for` loop:

```
for i in range(50):
    present_coefiecients = random.sample(xrange(1,50),5)
    present_value = random.sample(xrange(1,100),5)
    present_weights = ap.array('0;0;0;0;0')
    print present_coefiecients
    print present_value
    print present_weights
    c = [a*b for a,b in zip(present_coefiecients,present_value)]
    layer_1 = ap.log2(c)
    print layer_1
```